# Spring Boot MVC How to send a file to browser/user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

my entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTACHMENT")
public class Attachment extends JpaModel{

    @Column(name="FILE")
    private byte[] file;

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    // Other properties and setters and getters
}
```

However, it's in my bytes how would tell my Spring controller to return this as a file?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
@RequestMapping("/attachment")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAttachment() throws IOException {
    Attachment attachment = null; // Retrieve your attachment somehow
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).body(attachment.getFile());
}
```

or you can use this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/attachment", produces={ /* Types of files */ })
public byte[] getAttachment() {
    Attachment attachment = null; // Retrieve your attachment somehow
    return attachment.getFile();
}
```

Using the second approach you must set the possible types of the attachment in the `produces` param of `@RequestMapping`. The client will then have to request content type in the `Accept` header.

The first example allows you to set content type based on your attachment (I assume that you will have it stored in the DB somehow along with the content), which is probably what you need.

Comment: Well, the first version would be more readable if it was written as `return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).body(attachment.getFile());`

Comment: @zeroflagL Good point, thank you for the tip. I've updated the answer.